# Debug an executable without pdb outside visual studio

Tags: c#, windbg, remote-debugging

At a remote computer I need to debug an executable which is built in release mode. 
There is no Visual studio installed but the .Net framework is.

I read about windbg and remote debugging and other solutions fellow programmers suggested but the subject is vague and I don't have a complete overview of the subject and the options available for my condition.

There is a possibility i can get the .pdb file.

Edit: I know this post was marked as a duplicate. The difference with the other post is that i can not download or send large files like the Windows SDK and the computer does not have internet connectivity. As i said .net framework is installed. Where can i find `mdgb`??

Answer (score 0):

dotPeek by JetBrains can generate PDB files for you (and act as a Symbol Server). https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Introducing+JetBrains+dotPeek#IntroducingJetBrainsdotPeek-GeneratingPDBfiles